# ASP.Net Core MongoCSharpDriver 2.7 db is null in .GetDatabase

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to build a short ASP.Net WebAPI POC that connects to my Mongo Atlas cluster. I already have a working Node/Koa Rest api that connects and works perfectly. However, I can't get this ASP.Net Core MongoCSharpDriver 2.7 to connect. In subsequent controller code, when it tries to do _db.GetCollection("user").FindAll(), **_db is always null**

Can you see what I'm missing and/or post some example code that you have working?

```
const string DB_NAME = "easymessagebus";
const string DB_URL = "mongodb://**user**:**pass**@cluster0-shard-00-00-dhbdk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-dhbdk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-dhbdk.mongodb.net:27017/" + DB_NAME + "?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true";
const string COLL_NAME = "user";
MongoClient _client;
MongoDatabase _db;
public UserData()
{
    _client = new MongoClient(DB_URL);
    _db = _client.GetDatabase(DB_NAME) as MongoDatabase;
}
...
```

I can only assume my connection url must be changed in some way, but why doesn't the code throw a connection error?

Answer (score 0):

So the _db being null and debug run providing no error other than "_db is null..." (yeah not helpful), I had to Google on this one for quite a while.

After much Googling I finally found some code that provided the clue to finally solve my problem. It actually wasn't the connection, it was how was trying to retrieve the data. You MUST wrap all your controller and dataRepo/dataContext methods in **async Tasks**.

Here is a working UserData class for anyone searching on this later...

**UserData.cs**

```
public class UserData
{
    private readonly IMongoClient _mongoClient;
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;
    private readonly IMongoCollection<User> _collection;

    public UserData(string mongoUri)
    {
        _mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUri);
        _database = _mongoClient.GetDatabase("easymessagebus");
        _collection = _database.GetCollection<User>("user");
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _collection.Find(Builders<User>.Filter.Empty).ToListAsync();
    }

...
```

**UserController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/user")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserData userData = null;

    public UserController(string mongoUri)
    {
        userData = new UserData(mongoUri);
    }

    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get()
    {
        var values = await userData.GetAll();
        return new JsonResult(values);
    }

...
```

*NOTE: Make sure your appsettings.json includes your correct MongoDb Uri string. Also, make sure your Startup.cs passes the MongoDb Uri to your controller constructor like...*

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        var mongoUri = Configuration["MongoUri_Atlas"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mongoUri))
        {
            services.AddSingleton<string>(mongoUri);
        }
    }

...
```